# Mobile Safari and jQuery events, nothing is firing?

Tags: jquery, html, ios, mobile-safari, jquery-events

I have an app written in HTML5/JavaScript for an in-dash car unit.  It is a 'single-page' app with fragments loaded into divs on the main page in response to different events.

I've been asked to port it to the browser so that it can be used for marketing, presentations, whatever.

This didn't seem like a big deal since there was very little to adapt, just needed to adjust some CSS so that it could be displayed the same across all browsers.  Then, they decided that the device they wanted to run the webapp on would be an iPad.

The app worked great in Safari, so I didn't think I would have any issues with Mobile Safari.  Immediately realized that this was not the case.  The app doesn't work at all in Mobile Safari!  Basically, none of my click events are firing.  On top of that, I'm getting inconsistent error messages in my console that don't show up in any other browser.

> TypeError: 'null' is not an object

Going around this site, I'm seeing conflicting reports about what jQuery bindings work and Mobile Safari and which ones don't.  So I decided to set up my own experiment.

Creating a page with a single link:

```
<a class="mylink">CLICK ME</a>
```

I then tried each of these bindings:

```
$("a.mylink").click(function () { console.log("click worked"); });
$("a.mylink").bind("click", function () { console.log("bind worked"); });
$("a.mylink").live("click", function () { console.log("live worked"); });
$("a.mylink").on("click", function () { console.log("on worked"); });
```

The only one that I got any response in the console from was .live().  And even then, it was very inconsistent and usually involved spamming it with clicks.

If I edit my link and add an onclick attribute like so:

```
<a onclick="function(){}" class="mylink">CLICK ME</a>
```

Then .live() works consistently, but no other bindings still.  This seems insane to me since so many apps run on Mobile Safari just fine.  Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Note, I know how to use jQuery so before anyone asks, yeas my bindings are inside of `$(document).ready()`.
Also, I know that links work just fine once an href is attached to them, but that's obviously not what I need since this is a single-page navigation app, and attaching an href seems to ignore any bindings completely in iOS and causes a full page navigation.

Comment: Try putting `href="#"` on anchor tag and `return false;` in bound function, Also try putting `cursor:pointer` in css od `a`. Looks like its not understanding that your `anchor` is a clickable thing.

Comment: You could try wrapping it with AppMobi and using it as an actual App on the iPad. Chances are you wouldn't have to change any code...

Answer (score 10):

You either have to add a `href="#"` or put a `cursor:pointer` to the element being clicked.

Here is a test(in iPad 3): http://jsfiddle.net/dZqyU/2/

```
<a class="clickable">I have no href :( (I dont work in iPad)</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<a class="clickable" href="#">I have href :) (I work in iPad)</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<a class="clickable cursor">I have cursor, no href :) (I work in iPad)</a>
```

---

```
$(document).on('click','.clickable',function(){
    alert($(this).text() + 'and the binding worked :)');
});
```

---

```
.cursor{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

---

The issue I guess is like `a` anchor tag without `href` attribute is not identified as a clickable element by some iOS Safari versions. But if we explicitly make them `clickable` by adding `href` or add a cursor `pointer` it works. [Here is a related link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW6).

Comment: How would adding cursor:pointer or adding href help in getting the jQuery event to be fired?

Comment: Lol. I know it sounds illogical, but it does work. Probably a bug in safari iOS :)

Comment: @CodePoet I went through this issue once but couldn't remember the research i did, so kept the post intact despite of the down votes in case someone finds it useful  :)

Comment: iOS 6.1.3 Safari on iPhone 3GS - had a list of items in a ul > li configuration. Had a gradient div inside each li to allow for white text over the li background image. Using <a href="javascript:;"> worked, but I wanted to avoid using anchor tags because of a function in my js. So I reverted back to <div>'s and added cursor:pointer to my css. Worked beautifully. Since most developers try to produce current code, and as such use the latest jQuery, I don't have any issue using .on() to bind click or tap events.

Comment: @Lazerblade Thank you for mentioning here, please add this scenario as a question and answer it yourself when you get time, that way people with similar issues can easily hit this in a search.

Comment: @sabithpoker I was merely giving credence to your answer. Since the question and answer I'd be posting would end up being marked as a duplicate of this question and your answer, I wanted to avoid that scenario. However, if you feel that adding such a scenario might help, I can certainly do that. Just trying to avoid confusing duplication.

Comment: I ran into this trying to use the Bootstrap 3 collapse plugin.  @sabithpoker your solution to add cursor:pointer worked for me but I am still scratching my head as to WHY it works.

Comment: @SteveO7 Above tricks makes a DOM Node 'clickable' for the iOS Safari. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW6)

Answer (score 1):

What the previous answer states is incorrect.  I tested, and was able to implement what you are trying to achieve without the inline javascript, using only bind on an iPhone.  My guess is that you have some little typo somewhere, and because of jQuery's magical ability to degrade gracefully, there is no error getting called.

One thing you could try, assuming that what I said about the error is not correct, is to add the href="#" to your anchor, and then use event.preventDefault() [and you may also need to add event.stopImmediatePropagation()] to your code.

It seems highly likely that there is a bug in your code (perhaps somewhere completely different, and unrelated), that desktop Safari was kind enough to figure out for you, and overlook or fix, but mobile safari is much less forgiving in my experience.

Comment: Furthermore, it should not be in anyway relevant that it is an anchor.  You could do:  $('h2').click(function(){}) and it would work.  The only reason that it is even remotely relevant, is because an anchor can do something without javascript when clicked (href).  Your code would work on any visible element within the dom.  If you look at your code I promise you will find an error or a conflict.

Comment: The issue was poorly explained in my question which I now realize since I typed it up on little sleep.  The real issue is that since fragments are loaded in dynamically, some elements being bound to do not yet exist in the DOM.  This isn't a problem for .live and .on in desktop browsers, but .live and .on do not work as expected for Mobile Safari.

Comment: Depending on the exact nature of your code, jQuery.Deferred may be a solution, or you could put your code inside of a different binding, like $(document).bind("load") for example.  It also maybe handleable via Ajax.complete or Ajax.deferred.  It's hard to know from this end without seeing the code.  Though, to reiterate what I said earlier, The only time I experienced problems with .on or .live on mobile when they worked on the desktop, I had a problem in my code, and mobile wouldnt let me get away with it, even though desktop would.

Comment: I'm almost certain his javascript is being called in the head, before the a exists in the document.

Comment: But then what about the tests I did in ipad3 ios6?