# jQuery click event not firing in iOS Safari when connected to LTE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari, lte

I'm binding the following click event to an anchor tag after the page loads. The purpose is to track an event in Google Analytics before the *href* is followed:

```
$("a.my-link").on("click", function() {
   // Send Google Analytics click event before following href
}
```

When I'm connected with LTE using iOS Safari, the event is never fired before following the *href*.

If I switch to wi-fi, the event fires just fine. Furthermore, it also works on LTE if the *target* attribute of the anchor tag is set to "_blank" (i.e. new window). And it also works just fine on Chrome for iOS.

Has anyone run into this issue with iOS Safari on LTE?

It seems like some sort of bug (or intended feature?) to disable click events on anchor tags in certain circumstances.

Comment: This pops up in stackoverflow's sidebar in the related section and it seems very similar to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207180/mobile-safari-and-jquery-events-nothing-is-firing?rq=1

Comment: @AlexanderTrust, thanks, but the problem I'm having is different: the click event fires just fine when I'm connected to wi-fi, but not when I'm using LTE (mobile data).